# Add unique value from first column before each group

Tags: bash, awk

I have following file contents:

```
T12 19/11/19 2000 
T12 18/12/19 2040 

T15 19/11/19 2000 
T15 18/12/19 2080
```

How to get following output with awk,bash and etc, I searched for similar examples but didn't find so far:

```
T12 
19/11/19 2000 
18/12/19 2040 

T15 
19/11/19 2000 
18/12/19 2080
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: I'd probably create an associative array with the key as the first field and the value being a list of the remaining fields. Have you tried implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. This code will print output in same order in which first field is occurring in Input_file.

```
awk '
!a[$1]++ && NF{
  b[++count]=$1
}
NF{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i] ORS c[b[i]]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
T12
19/11/19 2000
18/12/19 2040
T15
19/11/19 2000
18/12/19 2080
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
!a[$1]++ && NF{                        ##Checking condition if $1 is NOT present in array a and line is NOT NULL then do following.
  b[++count]=$1                        ##Creating an array named b whose index is variable count(every time its value increases cursor comes here) and its value is first field of current line.
}                                      ##Closing BLOCK for this condition now.
NF{                                    ##Checking condition if a line is NOT NULL then do following.
  val=$1                               ##Creating variable named val whose value is $1 of current line.
  $1=""                                ##Nullifying $1 here of current line.
  sub(/^ +/,"")                        ##Substituting initial space with NULL now in line.
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] ORS:"")$0      ##Creating an array c whose index is variable val and its value is keep concatenating to its own value with ORS value.
}                                      ##Closing BLOCK for this condition here.
END{                                   ##Starting END block for this awk program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){               ##Starting a for loop which runs from i=1 to till value of variable count.
    print b[i] ORS c[b[i]]             ##Printing array b whose index is i and array c whose index is array b value with index i.
  }
}                                      ##Closing this program END block here.
'  Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}{printf "%s\n",$1; gsub($1" +",""); print}' file
```

**How does it work?**
Awk knows the concept *records* and *fields*.

Files are split in *records* where consecutive records are split by the record separator `RS`. Each record is split in fields, where consecutive fields are split by the field separator `FS`.

By default, the record separator `RS` is set to be the <newline> character (`\n`) and thus each record is a line. The record separator has the following definition:

> **`RS`:**
>   The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. **If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input**, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

So with the file format you give, we can define the records based on `RS=""`.

By default, the field separator is set to be any sequence of blanks. So `$1` will point to that particular word we want on the separate line. So we print it with printf, and then we remove any reference to it with `gsub`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll test it.

Comment: @JoeGreen you commented on the wrong answer (For Ravinder) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is very flexible and provides a number of ways to solve the same problem. The answers you have already are excellent. Another way to approach the problem is to simply keep a single variable that holds the current *field 1* as its value. (unset by default) When the first field changes, you simply output the first field as the current heading. Otherwise you output the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> fields. If a blank-line is encountered, simply output the newline.

```
awk -v h= '
    NF < 3 {print ""; next}
    $1 != h {h=$1; print $1}
    {printf "%s %s\n", $2, $3}
' file
```

Above are the 3-rules. If the line is empty (checked with number of fields less than three (`NF < 3`), then output the newline and skip to the next record. The second checks if the first field is not equal to your current heading variable `h` -- if not, set `h` to the new heading and output it. All non-empty records have the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> fields output.

**Result**

Just paste the command above at the command line and you will get the desired result, e.g.

```
awk -v h= '
>     NF < 3 {print ""; next}
>     $1 != h {h=$1; print $1}
>     {printf "%s %s\n", $2, $3}
> ' file
T12
19/11/19 2000
18/12/19 2040

T15
19/11/19 2000
18/12/19 2080
```